# Solr WordDelimiterFilter + Lucene Highlighter

Tags: java, solr, lucene, tokenize, lucene-highlighter

I am trying to get the Highlighter class from Lucene to work properly with tokens coming from Solr's WordDelimiterFilter.  It works 90% of the time, but if the matching text contains a ',' such as "1,500" the output is incorrect:

> Expected: 'test **1,500** this'
>
> Observed: 'test 1**1,500** this'

I am not currently sure whether it is Highlighter messing up the recombination or WordDelimiterFilter messing up the tokenization but something is unhappy.  Here are the relevant dependencies from my pom:

org.apache.lucene
    lucene-core
    2.9.3
    jar
    compile
   
   
    org.apache.lucene
    lucene-highlighter
    2.9.3
    jar
    compile
   
   
    org.apache.solr
    solr-core
    1.4.0
    jar
    compile

And here is a simple JUnit test class demonstrating the problem:

```
package test.lucene;


import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.HashMap;


import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.InvalidTokenOffsetsException;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.QueryScorer;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.SimpleFragmenter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.SimpleHTMLFormatter;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.solr.analysis.StandardTokenizerFactory;
import org.apache.solr.analysis.WordDelimiterFilterFactory;
import org.junit.Test;


public class HighlighterTester {
    private static final String PRE_TAG = "<b>";
    private static final String POST_TAG = "</b>";

    private static String[] highlightField( Query query, String fieldName, String text )
            throws IOException, InvalidTokenOffsetsException {
        SimpleHTMLFormatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter( PRE_TAG, POST_TAG );
        Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter( formatter, new QueryScorer( query, fieldName ) );
        highlighter.setTextFragmenter( new SimpleFragmenter( Integer.MAX_VALUE ) );
        return highlighter.getBestFragments( getAnalyzer(), fieldName, text, 10 );
    }

    private static Analyzer getAnalyzer() {
        return new Analyzer() {
            @Override
            public TokenStream tokenStream( String fieldName, Reader reader ) {
                // Start with a StandardTokenizer
                TokenStream stream = new StandardTokenizerFactory().create( reader );

                // Chain on a WordDelimiterFilter
                WordDelimiterFilterFactory wordDelimiterFilterFactory = new WordDelimiterFilterFactory();
                HashMap<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
                arguments.put( "generateWordParts", "1" );
                arguments.put( "generateNumberParts", "1" );
                arguments.put( "catenateWords", "1" );
                arguments.put( "catenateNumbers", "1" );
                arguments.put( "catenateAll", "0" );
                wordDelimiterFilterFactory.init( arguments );

                return wordDelimiterFilterFactory.create( stream );
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void TestHighlighter() throws ParseException, IOException, InvalidTokenOffsetsException {
        String fieldName = "text";
        String text = "test 1,500 this";
        String queryString = "1500";
        String expected = "test " + PRE_TAG + "1,500" + POST_TAG + " this";

        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser( Version.LUCENE_29, fieldName, getAnalyzer() );
        Query q = parser.parse( queryString );
        String[] observed = highlightField( q, fieldName, text );
        for ( int i = 0; i < observed.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( "\t" + i + ": '" + observed[i] + "'" );
        }
        if ( observed.length > 0 ) {
            System.out.println( "Expected: '" + expected + "'\n" + "Observed: '" + observed[0] + "'" );
            assertEquals( expected, observed[0] );
        }
        else {
            assertTrue( "No matches found", false );
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, this appears to be a bug in the Lucene Highlighter code.  As you can see here:

```
public class TokenGroup {

    ...

    protected boolean isDistinct() {
        return offsetAtt.startOffset() >= endOffset;
    }

    ...
```

The code attempts to determine if a group of tokens is distinct by checking to see if the start offset is greater than the previous end offset.  The problem with this approach is illustrated by this issue.  If you were to step through the tokens, you would see that they are as follows:

```
0-4: 'test', 'test'
5-6: '1', '1'
7-10: '500', '500'
5-10: '1500', '1,500'
11-15: 'this', 'this'
```

From this you can see that the third token starts after the end of the second, but the fourth starts the same place as the second.  The intended outcome would be to group tokens 2, 3, and 4, but per this implementation, token 3 is seen as separate from 2, so 2 shows up by itself, then 3 and 4 get grouped leaving this outcome:

```
Expected: 'test <b>1,500</b> this'
Observed: 'test 1<b>1,500</b> this'
```

I'm not sure this can be accomplished without 2 passes, one to get all the indexes and a second to combine them.  Also, I'm not sure what the implications would be outside of this specific case.  Does anyone have any ideas here?

EDIT

Here is the final source code I came up with.  It will group things correctly.  It also appears to be MUCH simpler than the Lucene Highlighter implementation, but admittedly does not handle different levels of scoring as my application only needs a yes/no as to whether a fragment of text gets highlighted.  Its also worth noting that I am using their QueryScorer to score the text fragments which does have the weakness of being Term oriented rather than Phrase oriented which means the search string "grammatical or spelling" would end up with highlighting that looks something like this "**grammatical** or **spelling**" as the or would most likely get dropped by your analyzer.  Anyway, here is my source:

```
public TextFragments<E> getTextFragments( TokenStream tokenStream,
        String text,
        Scorer scorer )
        throws IOException, InvalidTokenOffsetsException {
    OffsetAttribute offsetAtt = (OffsetAttribute) tokenStream.addAttribute( OffsetAttribute.class );
    TermAttribute termAtt = (TermAttribute) tokenStream.addAttribute( TermAttribute.class );
    TokenStream newStream = scorer.init( tokenStream );
    if ( newStream != null ) {
        tokenStream = newStream;
    }

    TokenGroups tgs = new TokenGroups();
    scorer.startFragment( null );
    while ( tokenStream.incrementToken() ) {
        tgs.add( offsetAtt.startOffset(), offsetAtt.endOffset(), scorer.getTokenScore() );
        if ( log.isTraceEnabled() ) {
            log.trace( new StringBuilder()
                    .append( scorer.getTokenScore() )
                    .append( " " )
                    .append( offsetAtt.startOffset() )
                    .append( "-" )
                    .append( offsetAtt.endOffset() )
                    .append( ": '" )
                    .append( termAtt.term() )
                    .append( "', '" )
                    .append( text.substring( offsetAtt.startOffset(), offsetAtt.endOffset() ) )
                    .append( "'" )
                    .toString() );
        }
    }

    return tgs.fragment( text );
}

private class TokenGroup {
    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;
    private float score;

    public TokenGroup( int startIndex, int endIndex, float score ) {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
        this.score = score;
    }
}

private class TokenGroups implements Iterable<TokenGroup> {
    private List<TokenGroup> tgs;

    public TokenGroups() {
        tgs = new ArrayList<TokenGroup>();
    }

    public void add( int startIndex, int endIndex, float score ) {
        add( new TokenGroup( startIndex, endIndex, score ) );
    }

    public void add( TokenGroup tg ) {
        for ( int i = tgs.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            if ( tg.startIndex < tgs.get( i ).endIndex ) {
                tg = merge( tg, tgs.remove( i ) );
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        tgs.add( tg );
    }

    private TokenGroup merge( TokenGroup tg1, TokenGroup tg2 ) {
        return new TokenGroup( Math.min( tg1.startIndex, tg2.startIndex ),
                Math.max( tg1.endIndex, tg2.endIndex ),
                Math.max( tg1.score, tg2.score ) );
    }

    private TextFragments<E> fragment( String text ) {
        TextFragments<E> fragments = new TextFragments<E>();

        int lastEndIndex = 0;
        for ( TokenGroup tg : this ) {
            if ( tg.startIndex > lastEndIndex ) {
                fragments.add( text.substring( lastEndIndex, tg.startIndex ), textModeNormal );
            }
            fragments.add( 
                    text.substring( tg.startIndex, tg.endIndex ),
                    tg.score > 0 ? textModeHighlighted : textModeNormal );
            lastEndIndex = tg.endIndex;
        }

        if ( lastEndIndex < ( text.length() - 1 ) ) {
            fragments.add( text.substring( lastEndIndex ), textModeNormal );
        }

        return fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<TokenGroup> iterator() {
        return tgs.iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you sent a patch to the mailing list? I just faced this bug too, and wasn't sure what it was. Would be awesome to get it fixed.

Comment: Sorry Dan, no I haven't.  The reason is, I cant figure out where.  I cant even find the bugzilla for Lucene let alone Lucene Highlighter.  Do you have the address of the mailing list?  Please post here and when I see it next, I will see if I can submit this suggestion.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/Lucene and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR — looks like this was addressed three weeks ago: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2874

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible cause.
Your highlighter needs to use the same Analyzer used for search. IIUC, Your code uses a default analyzer for the highlighting, even though it uses a specialized analyzer for parsing the query. I believe you need to change the Fragmenter to work with your specific TokenStream.

Comment: The code is using the same analyzer in both cases.  You can see above that it is actually created by the same helper method (getAnalyzer) both in the QueryParser constructor (for the query tokenizer) and by the highlighter.getBestFragments (for the text tokenizer).  This works except in the case with the , as this question indicates.  I do think I have found the problem and it is a bug in Lucene Highlighter.  I will post the answer below.